# Xcode Server bot builds ipa files for all simulators

Tags: xcode7, xcode-bots, xcode-server

Xcode Server Bot for Archive builds ipa for each the simulator separately, and one common ipa file. Is there a way of preventing it, having only the "compatible with all devices" ipa file?

What i tried so far:

- Unclicking Create user-installable product. Result: No `ipa` file is created.
- `Enable Bitcode` -> set NO For target&project's build settings. Result: Like in screenshot.

[image: Directory]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bot property.

Edit the bot, under configuration, under export choose "Installable Product"
[image]